# Give a domain group full control to the profile folders of all servers and workstations

Tags: windows, security, group-policy, profile, user-profile

I have a domain group (called GSG_TECH_USER) which need "full control" right to the folder "document & setting" of all servers and workstation.

I made a test with this configuration:

- On a workstation, add a local group LSG_PROFILE_RW
- Add the domain group GSG_TECH_USER to LSG_PROFILE_RW
- Go to the security of "Document & Settings" folder
- Add the group LSG_PROFILE_RW with "full control"
- Apply & test

Of course, the test fails, because inheritance is not checked for "doc & settings" folder.

Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks

Grégoire

**EDIT**
GSG_TECH_USER needs full control on folders & subfolders of "doc & settings".
In other words, on all profiles.
More precisely, GSG_TECH_USER should be able to create folder in %USERPROFILE% (c:\doc&setting\user\) of all the profiles present in the computer. In this created folder, it should be able to create files & folders.
The users of GSG_TECH_USER are technical users, not human users; so local admin rights is a solution, but not the best.

Comment: Do they need full control of JUST the Documents and Settings folder, or the folder and all of its subfolders?

Comment: Full control for the folders & subfolder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a domain group and add the domain group to the local administrators group.

Comment: I'm going to assume that there is a legitimate reason for not wanting to give full local admin to these people.

Least privilege, man!

Comment: i'm assuming that too, but since the OP didn't specify his security requirments I thought I'd put this out there. Let the OP do some work in describing his security needs instead of all of us having to write a thesis on it for him.

Comment: edit made, more details available, tell me if you need more

Comment: And I used the GPO/Restricted Groups functionallity

Answer (score 1):

Any chance you can just throw them in backup operators? Not the best solution, but it prevents them from having administrator, while still giving them full R/W access (though to all files on the system!!!)

Comment: It's not working ..